# Event template design

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I need to add Event details in kendo scheduler. Currently, it shows only the title name of the event.

Also I need to set some design in event list. Currently I am using ng-template inside kendo-scheduler. My HTML is like below:

```
<kendo-scheduler [kendoSchedulerBinding]="events"
 [selectedDate]="selectedDate" style="height: 400%; width: 100%;" >
                     <ng-template kendoSchedulerEventTemplate let-event="event" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on top">
                            {{ event.title }}
                            <br>
                            <span style="padding-top: 10px;">{{ event.description}}</span>
                        </ng-template>
<kendo-scheduler-month-view></kendo-scheduler-month-view>
<kendo-scheduler-week-view></kendo-scheduler-week-view>
<kendo-scheduler-day-view></kendo-scheduler-day-view>
</kendo-scheduler>
```

I am not able to understand how I format the template.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide your "events" and "resources" datas ?

Comment: I am not using resources  and my event data is

 "TaskID": 4,
        "OwnerID": 2,
        "Title": "N393BV",
        "Description": "Ron in LONDON (LUTON),GB CT/KL",
        "Start": "2019-10-28",
        "End": "2019-10-28",
        "IsAllDay": true